# PDO not throwing exception with unbound parameters (and no variables in query)

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

So I have no idea what's going on here

```
$link = new PDO('pgsql:dbname=' . $name . ';host=' . $host, $user, $password);
$link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

try {
    $stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT s.*, d.invalid_column FROM students s ORDER BY s.student_id");
    $stmt->execute(array(1));
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    print $e->getMessage();
}
```

When I run this little code example, I expect an exception to be thrown (as d.invalid_column is not a real column and I'm passing in parameters that cannot be bound), but the only thing that happens is that execute returns false and nothing else. Additionally `$stmt->errorInfo()` is blank and the code is `00000` which makes it hard to add a proper exception throw beyond something super generic with nothing else for the logs to assist me in tracking errors down when some end user reports an error.

If I add a single '?' somewhere to the query, the proper execution is thrown (that `d.invalid_column` is not a valid column), even if I add more parameters that don't bind to anything.

So ways to get this query to properly error:
1) Get rid all parameters
2) Add a '?' to the query

Is this just a bug in PDO or what?

edit:
Setups that will throw an exception (invalid column):

```
    $stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT s.*, d.invalid_column, ? FROM students s ORDER BY s.student_id");
    $stmt->execute(array(1));

    $stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT s.*, d.invalid_column, ? FROM students s ORDER BY s.student_id");
    $stmt->execute(array(1,2,3));

    $stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT s.*, d.invalid_column, ? FROM students s ORDER BY s.student_id");
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT s.*, d.invalid_column FROM students s ORDER BY s.student_id");
    $stmt->execute();
```

It's only when I have no `?` in my query and pass something to `execute()` that things just fail silently and with no explanation from PDO.

Comment: Why can't the parameters be bound? That makes *no* sense.

Comment: Because there's nothing for them (the ```$input_parameters``` in ```PDOStatement::execute()```) to bind to in this example? I found conflicting answers on whether specifying too many input parameters would throw an exception or not.

Comment: Typically the `execute()` would be empty if no parameters are being passed.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, Yes, ```execute()``` should be empty, but occasionally I make mistakes in refactoring queries where I removed all the binds from the query but forget to remove the array from execute. However, still doesn't explain why execute() is returning false with no error or indication as to why it is.

Comment: Check the result of `$dbErr = $stmt->errorInfo();`, I think you naming an invalid column directly into the statement raises exception in MySQL DB while parameter bindings (invalid or not) raises at PHP... it seems if no request of bindings are found inside the query, the parameters at execute will be ignored.

Comment: Using your original code, I can confirm that no exception is thrown. But I do see an error in `$stmt->errorInfo()` : `Unknown column 'd.invalid_column' in 'field list'`.

Comment: Actually, I forgot to include your `setAttribute` statements. With that, an exception *is* thrown: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'd.invalid_column' in 'field list'`. The error also appears in `$link->errorInfo()`.

Comment: PHP might be evaluating `array(1)` as `true`... or you're set to not display some errors (since it returns `false`).

Comment: I get an exception also (though testing with MySQL)

Comment: which is the php version?

Comment: My PHP version is 5.6.13 with Postgresql 9.4.

Comment: Mysql works as expected with the exception being thrown. Setting ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES to true does cause the exception to be thrown as expected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That behavior is reproducible with the current PHP (5.6.13), and the query is not even sent to the server.

Your case is described in [the doc](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) as:

> You cannot bind more values than specified; if more keys exist in
>   input_parameters than in the SQL specified in the PDO::prepare(), then
>   the statement will fail and an error is emitted.

0 value is expected, 1 value is given, and the statement fails, `false` being returned. So far, works as documented.

You may argue that "*an error is emitted*" would imply that when `ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` is on, an exception would be thrown. That's an argument, but it's not obvious that the PDO developers would agree with it.

Update:

***Why is `SQLCode` not set?***

Looking at PDO source code, specifically `static PHP_METHOD(PDOStatement, execute)` that handles PDO::execute(), you can see that all errors are handled by a macro: `PDO_HANDLE_STMT_ERR()`

```
#define PDO_HANDLE_STMT_ERR()   if (strcmp(stmt->error_code, PDO_ERR_NONE)) { pdo_handle_error(stmt->dbh, stmt TSRMLS_CC); }
```

The point is that, when passing a bound parameter when PDO expected none, the query never makes it to the SQL engine, so the SQL engine never has the opportunity to report an error accompanied with an SQLSTATE

PDO itself does not create a fake `SQLSTATE` on its own, at least no in that case, so`stmt->error_code` stays at `PDO_ERR_NONE` which is `"00000"`.

It's understandable that you would prefer an exception to be raised, but then you should suggest that to https://bugs.php.net

***Is it the same with MySQL ?***

Yes, the root behavior is the same except that with the MySQL driver, the `prepare` is sent immediately to the SQL engine so if it's incorrect because of a bad column, it fails earlier and with a real SQL error. On the other hand, the PgSQL driver has a different implementation that makes it defer the server-side `prepare`. This particular behavior is discussed in detail at [PHP Postgres PDO driver does not support prepared statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17492990/)

Anyway, here's a case with MySQL that demonstrates my explanation, that is:

- the query expects 0 parameter, 1 is given
- `$stmt->execute` returns false
- no exception gets raised
- PDO::errorCode is `00000`

Code:

```
$link = new PDO('mysql:dbname=' . $name . ';host=' . $host, $user, $password);
$link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

try {
    $stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT 1");
    $rc=$stmt->execute(array(1));
   if ($rc===false)
    echo "query failed, errorCode=", $link->errorCode(), "\n";
   else
    echo "query succeeded, errorCode=", $link->errorCode(), "\n";
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "A PDOException has occurred";
    print $e->getMessage();
}
```

Result:

> query failed, errorCode=00000

What happens under the hood is that the `prepare` is sent to the server and succeeds, but the `execute` step is cancelled by PDO due to the mismatch in parameters.

Here's a case that differs in the fact that the query refers to a non-existing column. I'm adding a print to show that `$stmt->execute` is not even called, as the exception is raised by `$stmt->prepare`

Code:

```
$link = new PDO('mysql:dbname=' . $name . ';host=' . $host, $user, $password);
$link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

try {
    $stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT nonexisting");
    echo "Executing query\n";
    $rc=$stmt->execute(array(1));
   if ($rc===false)
    echo "query failed, errorCode=", $link->errorCode(), "\n";
   else
    echo "query succeeded, errorCode=", $link->errorCode(), "\n";
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
  print "A PDOException has occurred";
    print $e->getMessage();
}
```

Result:

> A PDOException has occurredSQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054
>   Unknown column 'nonexisting' in 'field list'

Note how the "Executing query" step never happens, because it's the `prepare` that fails, server-side.

**Conclusion**

- when the query is sent to the server, be it in prepare() or execute(), and it's the server that generates an error, then we can expect a PDOException to be raised.
- when  the query is not sent to the server for an execution step, then PDO execute() can fail (returns false) but no exception is thrown and `errorCode()` stays at `00000`

Comment: I wouldn't consider getting a code of ```00000``` to be a satisfactory way to show an error considering that SQLCode means the query was supposed to work fine.

Comment: @MasterOdin: please see the lengthy update in the hope that it demonstrates my point, which I apparently failed to achieve in the first iteration.

Answer (score 3):

This was a bug in PDO and NikiC has recently fixed it. See bugs [#72368](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/9e3ba775b7de7d7647c488beb9e302d03690f955) and [#79131](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/15b51a215ac08fa72aa6ea44755f7134710f9004).

The problem was that PDO was not checking for errors coming from `EVT_ALLOC`. This was one of a number of issues related to error reporting that got fixed in the past few months.

If any of the methods in PDO return false without throwing an exception in the exception mode, then it is a bug. Please report any future bugs to https://bugs.php.net/ and if possible suggest a GitHub PR to fix it.